# Is it possible to execute a '.m' file from windows cmd like python

Tags: windows, cmd, octave

Please bear with me, I'm neither an Octave developer or Windows cmd developer. However I have found myself in a situation where the path of least resistance would be a cli solution. From Linux or Windows for that matter I can run Python ['test'].py - and expect to see nothing or something depending on what I want returned (e.g. if test.py had a line...

```
print('this is a test')
```

I could run and get

```
>python test.py
this is a test
```

So my question is if I have a matlab, or '.m' (something recognizable by Octave), is there a analog in octave to running the above as below

```
>octave test.m
```

I've tried

```
>octave --no-gui
```

That produces a separate command line version of octave - which could work if someone could help me understand how to chain a command such that once ran, the octave cli would execute the assigned octave.m file like

```
> octave --no-gui & test.m
```

My apologies if this is something obvious.

Comment: Did you look in [the documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Invoking-Octave-from-the-Command-Line.html)?

Comment: if `python test.py` is obvious, why haven't you tried `octave test.m` ?

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial try - ` octave test.m` if it does anything, it's not apparent.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes I checked the docs. From what I was able to gather and produce myself is more in the form of a separate and unique command line window, which still needs manual input of a .m file. Is there a flag to execute a .m and have output display to cmd?

Comment: Try this then: `octave  -q -f --no-gui test.m`

Comment: @CrisLuengo - thanks, yeah I've used that, but I get a new CMD window flash for a half-second and then it disappears with no content printed to my current CMD.

Comment: That makes no sense. It should use the current terminal for its output. What version of Octave do you have?

Comment: Octave-5.1.0.0> To be more transparent, although I'm not sure it matters. My 'script' that I'm trying to run takes a .csv file as an input and the expected output when run in octave is to print the lines. So, I would be trying to run test.m or octave -q -f --no-gui test('adsf.csv'). Both the test.m and the .csv are in the Octave-5.1.0.0 directory

Comment: I'm not sure Octave accepts a command to execute, the documentation talks about the name of a file. If you want to pass command-line arguments to your script, see [here](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Executable-Octave-Programs.html#Executable-Octave-Programs). -- Oh, that won't work on Windows, of course. You should try installing Cygwin, which provides bash and many tools useful on the command line. I bet that will solve all your problems! :)

Comment: Thank you for that, and I have install Cygwin and intend on trying to find a way to solve my problem that way. As interesting note - a colleague has Octave 3.8.2 and can run octave gui-less and execute a script so that the scripts contents display in-terminal. However, when attempting to run the same command on another machine with Octave 4.2.2 the feature doesn't execute the same way. Both 3.8.2 and 4.2.2 are running on Ubuntu machines. Thought that was interesting.

Comment: in windows, `octave.bat --no-gui test.m`

Comment: @Andy octave test.m doesn't run and feels like it may be redundant. test.m opens octave-gui.

Comment: @lostbard I don't see a octave.bat, I have post-instal.bat (which I ran) cmdshell.bat(which opens a MINgW64 CLI) and a fc_update.bat...I can run cmdshell.bat and then octave.bat. Are you aware of how one could chain cmdshell.bat  & octave.bat together?

Comment: its in the bin directory -> (mingw64\bin)

Comment: and to be complete because you are trying to call test with an argument in a previous comment: If you have a function test implemented in a file test.m and you want to call this function with an argument you have to `octave.bat --no-gui --eval 'test("foo.bar")'`

Comment: @Andy, this is a close to the answer I've been so far. So my flow now is: >cmdshell.bat  --- $ octave.bat --eval 'test("foobar.csv")'... Is there someway to chain one-liners in the fashion cmdshell.bat & $ octave.bat --eval 'test("foobar.csv")' ?? So close!!!

Comment: @Derek_P To chain Octave one-liners, just separate your statements with semicolons or boolean `&&`/`||` operators. `'disp('hello!'); test("foobar.csv"); x = 1 + 2; fprintf("x=%f\n", x);'` and so on. Or use commas instead of semicolons if you want Octave to automatically display the result of the statement. And just be careful with your nested quotes. Or are you asking how to chain one-liners in a bat file?